# Emails does not send to hotmail.com and live.com

Tags: c#, email, sendmail

I use following code to send email from my Windows application:

```
    public bool SendEmail(string to, string subject, string body, bool isHtml, List<string> bcc, List<string> cc, string fullname)
    {
        var from = "myname@myDomain.com";
        var name = "MyName";
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(to, fullname);
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(from, name);

        var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = isHtml
        };

        if (bcc != null && bcc.Any())
            foreach (var bccItem in bcc)
                message.Bcc.Add(bccItem);

        if (cc != null && cc.Any())
            foreach (var ccItem in cc)
                message.CC.Add(ccItem);

        var key = "password";
        var domain = "webmail.mydomain.com";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = domain,
            Port = 587,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, key)
        };

        try
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.Write(exception);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but not with **hotmail.com** and **live.com** and **outlook.com**. When I try to send an email to, for example, someone@hotmail.com, the procedure works good, but the someone@hotmail.com does not received sent email, even in junk folder. What's the problem? What's my mistake?

Comment: Do email recepients on any other domain (Gmail, Yahoo, etc) receive emails correctly?

Comment: Yes, it works on Gmail and yahoo

Comment: Roughly how many emails do you send out? Perhaps your SMTP server is temporarily blacklisted.

Comment: @TyCobb maybe 1 to 5 per day

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your hotmail.com? i had this problem before where hotmail thought i was a bot (obviously since u are sending from ur own application it had flagged it)

so what i would do is log in to your hotmail account via outlook.com. most likely it will tell you to "verify" that its you. to get rid of this problem all you have to do is activate that account via a mobile phone and it won't ask you to verify next time if u send email from your application. otherwise, every now and then you will have to login to outlook.com and "verify" that its you. wich can be annoying to do over and over again.

Comment: I don't send emails from my hotmail account. I send from my webmail to hotmail.

Comment: ah sorry i thought you were sending the email through hotmail/outlook